# QSerialPort proper sending of many lines

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, qtserialport

I am trying to write really big files to serialport using QSerialPort (QT 5.3.1). The problem is - I keep sending more than device can handle. 
Programm works like this (this function is called once in 50ms):

```
void MainWindow::sendNext()
{
    if(sending && !paused && port.isWritable())
    {
        if(currentLine >= gcode.size()) //check if we are at the end of array
        {
            sending = false;
            currentLine = 0;
            ui->sendBtn->setText("Send");
            ui->pauseBtn->setDisabled("true");
            return;
        }
        if(sendLine(gcode.at(currentLine))) currentLine++; //check if this was written to a serial port
        ui->filelines->setText(QString::number(gcode.size()) + QString("/") + QString::number(currentLine) + QString(" Lines"));
        ui->progressBar->setValue(((float)currentLine/gcode.size()) * 100);
    }
}
```

But it eventually gets flawed and hangs (on the device, not on the PC). If only I could check somehow if the device is ready or not for next line, but I cant find anything like it in the QSerial docs. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `QSerialPort::waitForBytesWritten` to ensure that the bytes are written. However this function would block the thread and it's recommended to use it in a new thread, otherwise your main thread would be blocked and your application freezes periodically.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this suggestion only helps when you're overflowing the output buffer on the PC side (essentially by trying to write more than the configured baud rate, and thus gradually filling up the output buffer). However if the device input buffer is the problem (more probable), riodoro1's answer is more useful: use the flow control capabilities of the serial protocol. See QSerialPort::setFlowControl, and requestToSend/dataTerminalReady, and only continue to send if the device reports it's ready.

Answer (score 1):

The RS232 does have some flow control capabilities.
Check if Your device uses RTS/CTS and if so change the connection properties to use hardware flow control.
The QSerialPort also allows for checking the flow control lines manually with `dataTerminalReady` or `requestToSend`

Comment: Even software flow control (`setFlowControl(QSerialPort::SoftwareControl)`) should fix the poster's issue.